# Puzzle of Random Numbers

Tags: calculation-puzzle, cipher

My friend sent me his puzzle: it's `S2LQEQnXk4DP+WsyP1aURD+lz4JSteeOPz3tO7Yiu1dv5fFCr31uegHUpVGqyXk7WjX95TDALus8Gj6nnoGHwj0MLE2AfpB2KTQEIxVvGMyun2XLb+PTcqzVAoFQLr48` in binary, and it came with two hints: "PooP" and "3 6 4 2 5 -5 -4 -6 0 -5".

We have been giving each other these puzzles for a time now and they have been words or phrases so far, but this one may be more complicated. Yes I know my friend is immature.

Edit:
Check comments for how I got there, but I have gotten it down to "Aid kIe CT" and the numbers.

Comment: I've made some progress. It was encrypted with AES. I decrypted it twice using the code Poop. Now I have "Aid kIe CT" and the numbers! Let's solve it!

Comment: "it's ... in binary" doesn't really make sense. Are you saying that you converted a large binary string to characters by ASCII encoding? That's one of many ways to convert between numbers and characters; in general you might want to be aware of other ways of encoding characters into numbers. If there wasn't already an apparently correct answer, I'd recommend stating your conversion more explicitly in case it was incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

adding/subtracting the numbers from the position they are currently at (including spaces) you get a message that i'm not sure is allowed on the site.

take "Aid KIe CT" and assign positional values with base 1. Add the corresponding number to the position and align it in it's new position. For example

```
A is position 1 and the first number is 3 so A's new position is 4. 
Likewise for i it is position 2 and 6 is the second number so i's new position is 8.
```

the answer is 10 characters with 2 spaces.

> I eAT d***

"Yes I know my friend is immature."

```
Indeed. He also has a poor diet.
```